# how to get a particular user data from MongoDB in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, e-commerce

I'm doing a project on an e-commerce website. here I'm with a problem.

1. I have used the get method to retrieve user data from MongoDB
2. I have passed the correct parameters and the statement UserId:req.params.userId has been satisfied where we can see in the nodejs terminal.
3. I'm looking to get only particular user data with UserId === UserId. But in my result, all the user's data is popping up.

Im trying this but the solution im getting is all the users data

i have tried using findOne() but the result is this 635ea7e5e931e12c9f851dd3 user details. where the parameter is 63a8a0f77addf42592eed1e5. where im expecting to get the only user which im passing in parameter.

```
router.get("/find/:userId", verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cart = await Cart.find( 
    {userId : req.params.userId});
    console.log("parameter: "+req.params.userId)
     return res.status(200).json(cart);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
```

The req.params userId is '63a8a0f77addf42592eed1e5'. i need only this. but it is popping up all the users data.

Node.js terminal showing the parameter is same with userId

[image]

Postman showing the response of all users present in the DB but i need only the user details which i had passed in the parameter

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here the mongoDB `find` method returns all data in the collection, irrespective of the parameters that we pass in to it. Instead try using the `findOne` method for that collection. So the code with correction will be as follows:

```js
router.get("/find/:userId", verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cart = await Cart.findOne( 
    {userId : req.params.userId});
    console.log("parameter: "+req.params.userId)
     return res.status(200).json(cart);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
```

You can read more about the method at [MongoDB Manual](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/).

Comment: in have tried that but the response I'm getting is other user. not the user I'm passing in the parameter. although I found the answer using filter method

Comment: Actually, `findOne` method returns a single record that matches the query passed in to it, and it is not suggested to use `filter` afterwords if not required. In this case, I don't think using `filter` is a good approach.

Answer (score -1):

I had found the solution for my problem i.e I have used filter method at (`res(200).json(cart.filter(((user)=>user.UserId === req.params.userId)`)

This means

1. Using filter method `UserId` in my model === to the parameters `userId`

```js
router.get("/find/:userId", verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cart = await Cart.find( 
    {userId : req.params.userId});
    console.log("parameter: "+req.params.userId)
      res.status(200).json(cart.filter((user)=>user.UserId === req.params.userId));
     console.log(cart.filter((user)=>user.UserId === req.params.userId))
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: filtering data using filter method is not the proper approach to satisfy your needs. Instead use findOne method of mongoose.

Comment: Hi @DrashtiKheni I have used findOne method but the result I’m getting for it is the first user in my MongoDB collection not the user I’m passing as a parameter

Comment: Can you add schema file for cart?